# What's wrong with my SWTOR launcher?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So, when I try to load up the Star Wars The Old Republic launcher, it doesn't load up, but it says "Unable to load application configuration". How do I fix this? (By the way, I know nothing about computers)

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the shortcut and choose Properties →  Compatibility.  Set the compatibility mode to the previous version of Windows (XP SP3 if you're using 7, and 7 SP1 if you're using 8/8.1), and set it to run as Administrator.
2. Make sure you have the Visual C++ runtime installed (the game includes it under in the install folder under "extras", by default: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Electronic Arts\BioWare\Star Wars - The Old Republic\extras\vc2008redist_x86.exe`).  You [should also install QuickTime](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=37323&page=3) and run Windows Update.
3. Add firewall and antivirus exceptions for `launcher.exe` (in the main install folder) and `swtor.exe` (under `install folder\swtor\retailclient`).
4. Reboot and try running the game.

If all that doesn't work, follow the steps here: [Why won't my SWTOR Launcher open?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49715/6066)